# There is a way to make a request with WHERE date = MAX(date)

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, where-clause

I would like to know if it was possible to make a request with an operator as his in postgresql :

```
WHERE date = MAX(date)
```

Thanks you

Comment: I think you need to be doing an aggregation (using GROUP BY) to do that, have a look at how the HAVING clause works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.date desc
limit 1;
```

Or, if you want to get duplicates, use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2);
```